# Is it possible to apply a whole manifest in a single API call

Tags: kubernetes

I am perfectly aware of the Kubernetes API and that a manifest can be broken down in several K8S API calls.

I am wondering if there is a way to apply a whole manifest at once in a single API call. A REST equivalent to `kubectl apply`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The feature is still in alpha but yes, it's called "server-side apply". Given the in-flux nature of alpha APIs, you should definitely check the KEPs before using it, but it's a new mode for the PATCH method on objects.

Comment: Link to docs for [Server Side Apply](https://kubernetes.io/docs/reference/using-api/api-concepts/#server-side-apply)